# Deploy ant build.xml to web Sphere

Tags: oracle, ibm-mq, java-ee-6, python-re

I have 3 images(oracle,websphere,mq) and application jee contient ant build.xml
and I want to create docker composer and build application and deployed in websphere

Comment: ...and your question is? Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.